# Android Library read from caller's manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library, android-configchanges

New to android development and asking for best practices around the following.

I am building a library for multiple apps.  One of the parameters I have for the library calls is the appname.  Can I pick this up from a parent config file to clean up the api interface so it's not required everywhere?  I have the same question around passing around the Context but I guess that might not be as easy due to security reasons.

If you can read the callers config, the next question is can should I require this appname parameter to be added this to the callers manifest?

Comment: Is it possible to get access to the callers resource (R) via context object and checking for a string there?

Comment: I will just add it to the constructor and can remove from the apis, but if you know another way please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I pick this up from a parent config file to clean up the api interface so it's not required everywhere?

There is no such concept as a "config file" in Android. If you mean "manifest file" (per your title), then you can't really read the manifest file in general.

Either have the hosting application pass in this value, or have the hosting application pass in its package name (so you can look this information up in `PackageManager`), or get the package name from a `Context` that the hosting application passes in (so you can use `PackageManager`).

> the next question is can should I require this be added this to the callers manifest?

Require *what* to "be added this to the callers manifest"? The package name is already there. The `android:label` for the application is already there -- you get this from `PackageManager`.

Comment: I should add that I want will additional values that are not android dependant.